# Auth0 login in a modal window in Node.js app

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, ejs

just started with node.js and auth0. have followed this guide on auth0 website - [Build and Authenticate a Node Js App with JSON Web Tokens](https://auth0.com/blog/building-and-authenticating-nodejs-apps/)

I am using ejs as my template engine, here is the login router:

```
router.get('/login',function(req, res){
    res.render('login', { env: env });
});
```

And the login.html view:

```
    <div id="root" style="width: 280px; margin: 40px auto; padding: 10px;">
          <script src="https://cdn.auth0.com/js/lock/10.12.1/lock.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 var lock = new Auth0Lock('<%= env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID %>', '<%= env.AUTH0_DOMAIN %>', { auth: {
          redirectUrl: '<%= env.AUTH0_CALLBACK_URL %>'
        , responseType: 'code'
        , params: {
          scope: 'openid name email picture'
        }
      }});
    lock.show();
 </script>
```

I am not very familiar with node and js, but is there any way for implementing Auth0 login window not on a different page (`login.html` in my case) but in a popup modal window which can be accesed on any page?

Comment: Yes, just include that bit of HTML on every page except for `lock.show()`. Then call `lock.show()` when you want to display the modal.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I do something similar where I call the login from a button in my navigation bar. Looks something like this:

```
<a class="button" onclick="lock.show();">Login</a>
```